# pgfplotstable will not generate table

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have some data from a table that I would like to tableize with `pgfplotstable`.
After many hours of going through the `pgfplotstable` 1.10 manual and basicly copying the example code with my data. Are the date and time formats a problem? I am just looking to handle those as strings. Is that a problem for the read routines? I created a small subset of the data without date/time colums with the same results. Even specifying only one column, "bikes", changes nothing. It continually complains about:

> ! Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@addpath was
>   complete.

I've spent several hours pulling out my thinning hair over this. Could someone please take a look at my relatively simple example and make suggestions. I am trying to learn `pgfplots`/`pgfplotstable` and I've hit a wall. Do I have a package conflict? Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

My code is below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,letterpaper,left=0.5in,
        right=0.5in,top=0.8in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfcalendar}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{filecontents}{bikesummary.dat}
date    bike     dist speed time    maxs  cada  heart heartmax massbr massar dmass
3/10/14 Yel-11   12.5 11.1  1:07:07 22.2   0.0    0.0   0.0      0.0  218.0  0.0
4/23/14 Fuji     16.5 14.0  1:11:20 29.7   0.0    0.0   0.0    219.2  218.8  0.4
5/18/14 8000SHX  21.0  9.2  2:15:14 32.5   0.0    0.0   0.0    219.0  217.2  1.8
5/24/14 Yel-11   24.2 10.1  2:23:39 30.5   0.0    0.0   0.0    219.0  216.6  2.4
5/29/14 YFoil77  23.4 15.5  1:28:38 33.2  75.0    0.0   0.0    219.6  217.2  2.4
5/30/14 Y-22     21.1 10.5  2:02:17 27.0   0.0    0.0   0.0    219.6  218.8  0.8
6/01/14 YFoil77  23.9 15.3. 1:33:41 31.7  78.0    0.0   0.0    219.2  217.8  1.4
6/05/14 Fuji     32.3 13.6  2:21:14 35.2   0.0  102.0 102.0    218.0  217.0  1.0
6/17/14 YFoil77  23.8 15.2  1:33:29 36.9  76.0  156.0 174.0    218.4  217.2  1.2
6/22/14 YFoil77  27.0 15.5  1:44:41 35.2  78.0  154.0 175.0    217.0  215.6  1.4
6/27/14 Y-22     34.0 10.1  3:17:13 31.1   0.0    0.0   0.0    218.0  215.0  3.0
6/29/14 Fuji     20.0 15.1  1:19:49 34.8   0.0    0.0   0.0    218.8  217.0  1.8
7/09/14 YFoil77  35.3 15.0  2:21:27 35.2  74.0    0.0   0.0    217.4  215.6  1.8
7/12/14 Fuji     36.5 14.4  2:29:51 34.8   0.0   86.0  86.0    217.4  216.0  1.4
7/17/14 YFoil77  33.2 15.3  2:10:14 34.8  76.0   84.0 165.0    220.0  217.2  2.8
7/23/14 YFoil77  25.4 15.7  1:37:00 32.4  80.0  150.0 177.0    218.2  218.0  0.2
7/25/14 YFoil77  17.4 16.2  1:08:14 33.5  81.0  110.0 169.0    220.6  218.4  2.2
7/31/14 YFoil77  38.7 14.8  2:36:22 36.1  78.0  145.0 171.0    219.4  216.8  2.6
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{bikesummary.dat}\sumdata

\begin{document}
% Print the table
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={bike,dist,speed},
  % Booktabs rules
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=[3ex]\bottomrule},
  % Set header name
  columns/bike/.style={string type,column name=Bike},

  % Format numbers and titles
  columns/dist/.style={column name=Distance,fixed,precision=1,
                       fixed zerofill,dec sep align},
  columns/speed/.style={column name=Speed,fixed,precision=1,
                        fixed zerofill,dec sep align}
]\sumdata
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice question, and good MWE :) You'll notice that your question was edited to remove the upper case letters, as they are most often interpreted as shouting/anger - hope this helps :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Removing the empty line before `columns/dist/.style` fixes the problem. Afterwards, `pgfplotstable` complains that `15.3.` is no valid number, removing the period compiles your table successfully

Comment: Thank you for the help! I made the 2 corrections but I now get the following:                                               "! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'Yel-11' as a floating point number". Where do I go from here? Regards, Dave.

Comment: Right after my previous post, I uncommented the table column descriptions where bike is a string, voila, it works. Every column must default to floating point. It works and I'm happier. Thanks, Dave.